# Find and replace csv strings using a list in python

Tags: python, csv

I have this so far.

```
import csv

ifile = open('file', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(ifile,delimiter='\t')
ofile = open('file', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t')


findlist = ['A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'Y', 'R', 'W', 'S', 'K', 'M', 'X', 'N', '-']
replacelist = ['AA', 'GG', 'CC', 'TT', 'CT', 'AG', 'AT', 'GC', 'TG', 'CA', 
'NN', 'NN', '-']

rep = dict(zip(findlist, replacelist))

def findReplace(find, replace):
    s = ifile.read()
    s = s.replace(find, replace)
    ofile.write(s)

for item in findlist:
    findReplace(item, rep[item])

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

What it does is replaced the A with AA. However what I want is to replace all of the letters with the ones in the `replacelist`. I am very new to python and can't quite figure out why its not replacing everything.

```
HE670865    399908  N   N   N   N   N
HE670865    399910  N   N   N   N   N
HE670865    399945  T   T   N   T   T
HE670865    399951  R   R   N   A   A
HE670865    399957  A   A   N   A   A
HE670865    399978  C   C   C   M   C
HE670865    399980  C   C   C   C   C
HE670865    399982  T   T   T   T   K
HE670865    399984  C   C   C   C   C


HE670865    399908  N   N   N   N   N
HE670865    399910  N   N   N   N   N
HE670865    399945  T   T   N   T   T
HE670865    399951  R   R   N   AA  AA
HE670865    399957  AA  AA  N   AA  AA
HE670865    399978  C   C   C   M   C
HE670865    399980  C   C   C   C   C
HE670865    399982  T   T   T   T   K
HE670865    399984  C   C   C   C   C
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you are reading and writing inside the loop.

```
rep = dict(zip(findlist, replacelist))

s = ifile.read()
for item in findlist:
    s = s.replace(item, rep[item])
ofile.write(s)
```

Also, I think your code would be more readable (and more concise), without using the unnecessary `dict`.

```
s = ifile.read()
for item, replacement in zip(findlist, replacelist):
    s = s.replace(item, replacement)
ofile.write(s)
```

Comment: I didn't get the reason for the question code not working. Was it because of the function usage resulting in localized variables? I tried with `ifile` & `ofile` as strings & that was the error in my code.

Comment: Since you read and wrote for every replace, `ifile` had already been read all the way to the end after the first iteration. So `ifile.read()` was returning the empty string after the first iteration.