# Replace items in a CSV file Python using a list

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, replace

I have a list like below:

```
['data-data analysis','word or words-phrase','rank-ranking']
```

and a regular CSV file which could contain the word before "-" anywhere in it (any column). I'd like to replace those with the words after "-". A sample CSV file could be like below:

```
h1,h2,h3
data of database,a,v
gg,word or words/word,gdg
asd,r,rank
```

I really appreciate any help.

Desired output:

```
h1,h2,h3
data analysis of database,a,v
gg,phrase/word,gdg
asd,r,ranking
```

Comment: This question looks pretty close  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748676/find-and-replace-csv-strings-using-a-list-in-python

Comment: @BobHaffner Yeah I tried that but my output file looks strange. It didn't replace anything and moreover the entire table is repeated 29 times in the same file.

Comment: can you include the desired output?

Comment: @Jasper Please find the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has some trickery so you don't get `data analysis of data analysisbase` when replacing `data`:

#### input.csv

```
h1,h2,h3
data of database,a,v
gg,word or words/word,gdg
asd,r,rank
```

#### Python code

```
#!python2
import csv
import re

# This builds a dictionary of key/value replacements.
# It wraps the key in word breaks to handle not replacing
# "database" when the key is "data".
L = ['data-data analysis','word or words-phrase','rank-ranking']
pairs = [w.split('-') for w in L]
replacements = {r'\b' + re.escape(k) + r'\b':v for k,v in pairs}

# Files should be opened in binary mode for use with csv module.
with open('input.csv','rb') as inp:
    with open('output.csv','wb') as outp:

        # wrap the file streams in csv reader and csv writer objects.
        r = csv.reader(inp)
        w = csv.writer(outp)

        for line in r:
            for i,item in enumerate(line):
                for k,v in replacements.items():
                    item = re.sub(k,v,item)
                line[i] = item
            w.writerow(line)
```

#### output.csv

```
h1,h2,h3
data analysis of database,a,v
gg,phrase/word,gdg
asd,r,ranking
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I want but it says "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack" pointing to replacements = {r'\b' + re.escape(k) + r'\b':v for k,v in pairs}

Comment: @amy, what version of Python are you using?  Also, that could happen if you don't have a hyphen in one of your replacement strings.  Are you using the exact code above?

Comment: Yes. I used the exact code. Also, I'm using Python 2.7.6. There is a hyphen in all replacement strings.

Comment: The above code is Python 3, so it gets an error for me after that line.  Did you change the list `L`?  I'll make a version compatible with 2.7.

Comment: @amy Updated for Python 2.

Comment: Thank you. I did not change anything. Also, could you tell me how to input the csv file as a string.

Comment: I've updated the example to read from `input.csv` and write to `output.csv` using Python 2.7.