# How to count time for members connected to my discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently trying to count time for active members of my discord with discord bot in python. I write name of member and timedelta to the file.
My question is how can I read this timedelta from a file? I know that datetime.datetime has strptime method but there is none for datetime.timedelta.
Any ideas apart from slicing and passing this as arguments to timedelta constructor?

```
for a in self.members:
        if not a.bot:
            self.member_timers[a.name] = {}
            self.member_timers[a.name]['Time'] = None
            self.member_timers[a.name]['Stop'] = None
            self.member_timers[a.name]['Start'] = None
    self.read()

def read(self):
    lines = []
    with open(f'logi', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
    print(lines)
    line = lines[0].split()
    
def write(self):
    with open(f'logi', 'w') as f:
        for mem in self.members:
            if not mem.bot and self.member_timers[mem.name]['Time'] != None:
                f.write("{} {}\n".format(mem.name, self.member_timers[mem.name]['Time']))

def start_timer(self, member):
    if self.member_timers[member.name]['Start'] == None:
        self.member_timers[member.name]['Start'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    else:
        #policz mu czas zeby nie stracic
        self.count_time(member.name)
        self.member_timers[member.name]['Start'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        pass

def stop_timer(self, member):
    if self.member_timers[member.name]['Start'] != None:
        self.member_timers[member.name]['Stop'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.count_time(member.name)

def count_time(self, name):
    if self.member_timers[name]['Start'] != None and self.member_timers[name]['Stop'] != None:
        if self.member_timers[name]['Time'] == None:
            self.member_timers[name]['Time'] = self.member_timers[name]['Stop'] - self.member_timers[name]['Start']
        else:
            self.member_timers[name]['Time'] += self.member_timers[name]['Stop'] - self.member_timers[name]['Start']
        self.member_timers[name]['Start'] = None
        self.member_timers[name]['Stop'] = None
```

So when reading from file I want to create timedelta object for member so I can later compare if it's bigger than any role timedelta I have assigned.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A few things when you post your question. 1. Show us your code. 2. Share Sample Data. 3. Share Expected Output. 4.Check if similar question has already been asked. If so, you already have answers in other threads. I recommend doing #4 first.

Comment: For your question, you need to first read the data. It will read as string. Then use strptime to convert to datetime

Comment: Also look into this thread... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250152/format-date-string-in-a-file-using-python

Comment: Using strptime will get me datetime object and I need timedelta.

Comment: share sample data so i can answer. It looks like you want to do a timedelta based on a point in time. Once I have more info, can provide recommendation

Comment: Why do you need a timedelta? What's the reason for it? It doesn't make any sense at all

Comment: How other I can measure time for active member on my server? I measure time when he speaks or is not muted and then I want to give him role if he is active for more than 3 hours, 9 hours etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider storing the timestamp instead of storing timedelta object.

You can use `ts = datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.now())` to get a float (you can convert it to an int if you are only interested in seconds) that you store in your dictionnary.

To read it, you can use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)` and this will give you a `datetime.datetime` object corresponding to the timestamp you created above

References:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=timestamp#datetime.datetime.timestamp
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=fromtimestamp#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp